# Correct Regex for Acronyms In Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find so called Acronyms in text is this the correct way of defining the regex for it?
My idea is that if something starts with capital and ends with capital letter it is acronym. Is this correct?

```
import re
test_string = "Department of Something is called DOS, 
or DoS,  or (DiS) or D.O.S. in United State of America, U.S.A./ USA"
pattern3=r'([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]|(?:[A-Z]\.)+)'
print re.findall(pattern3, test_string)
```

and the out put is:

```
['DOS', 'DoS', 'DiS', 'D.O.S.', 'U.S.A.', 'USA']
```

Comment: Do you want to know if your regex is correct or if your definition of acronym is appropriate?

Comment: Not according to the definition on wikipedia. [An acronym is an abbreviation pronounced as a word. They are formed from the initial components in a phrase or a word - usually individual letters (as in NATO or laser); or parts of words or names (as in Benelux).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym)

Comment: You'd probably get most of them.  But you won't get acronyms with numbers (3D), or periodic elements (Ni), or lowercase (lb. i.e.), though these might be better described as abbreviations than acronyms.

Comment: @StefanReinhardt both.

Comment: @HåkenLid I think this definition serves what I need. thanks for letting me know

Comment: @BrendanAbel your very right about abbreviations like 3D, do you have any suggestions to determine them using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that you can use the word boundary \b anchor for what you want to do

```
>>> regex = r"\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[A-Z]\b\.?"
>>> re.findall(regex, "AbIA AoP U.S.A.")
['AbIA', 'AoP', 'U.S.A.']
```

Comment: Thanks for your cleaner regex. Could you tell why the boundary is  better in your idea?

Comment: Is there a way to exclude strings like: II, III, IV representing numbers?